# How would I change a particular string in a PDF file?

Tags: php

With the help of a PHP Class called EZPDF.

Comment: its help if you add link to the class you use

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
<?php 
 include ('class.ezpdf.php'); 
 $pdf = new Cezpdf();
 $pdf->selectFont('./fonts/Helvetica.afm'); 
 $pdf->ezText('Hello World!',50); 
 $pdf->ezStream(); 
?>
```